# Google App Engine and SQL Instance connection with Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-5.4, google-cloud-sql, app.yaml

I am trying to connect two Google SQL instances on Google App Engine using Laravel, but I don't know if I am doing it correctly. I am getting an error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table ‘[DATABASE2].[TABLE]’ doesn't exist.

When I only connect a SQL instance, I don't have any problem.

This is my "app.yaml" file:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: [APP_KEY]
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database

  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  # Instance 1 database connection
  DB_CONNECTION: [DATABASE1]
  DB_HOST: [SQL-INSTANCE1]
  DB_DATABASE: [DATABASE1]
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: [DB-PASSWORD-INSTANCE1]
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/[PROJECT]:[REGION]:[SQL-INSTANCE1]"

  # Instance 2 database connection
  DB_2_HOST: [SQL-INSTANCE2]
  DB_2_DATABASE: [DATABASE2]
  DB_2_USERNAME: root
  DB_2_PASSWORD: [DB-PASSWORD-INSTANCE2]
  DB_2_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/[PROJECT]:[REGION]:[SQL-INSTANCE2]”

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "[PROJECT]:[REGION]:[SQL-INSTANCE1],[PROJECT]:[REGION]:[SQL-INSTANCE2]"
```